# Codeshare flight - CM702 - GRU to PTY ticket sold by Emirates Airlines via COPA Airlines

Tags: air-travel, tickets, code-share

I bought a ticket from Emirates website for CMB to DXB, DXB to GRU, GRU to PTY. This is all a single ticket issued by Emirates. In this ticket, GRU to PTY is operated by COPA airlines (CM702 flight number).

After the order, I selected my seats for CMB to DXB flight and DXB to GRU flight.

How do I select the seats for GRU to PTY? The Emirates website is saying seat selection isn't available for flights operated by other carries. I took the ticket number and plugged it into COPA airlines website and it's saying that seat selection is not available for this passenger.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you use the correct six letter/digit reference, i.e. the COPA booking reference and not the Emirates reference (which is probably different) or the ticket number (which is a long string of numbers starting with 176).

Seat selection on code share is always hit or miss. Sometimes it's free, sometimes it can be done for a fee and sometimes, it's not available at all.

You can always select seats when you check-in. To make sure you still have a good selection, check in as early as possible.

In your case, you will probably be just fine: Your check-in window opens 23 or 24 hours before your first leg and since you have a whole lot of flying to do before you get to GRU, you are likely to be one of the first passengers to check-in and grab seats. It's also unlikely that the flights are full, so you should have plenty of good options to choose from.

Comment: Problem is, COPA airlines website state that you cannot mobile check in if the ticket is sold by a different airline. I would need to go to the COPA counter which is behind immigration at GRU airport. Is there another way to check in early? I don't know if GRU has check in kiosks at the terminal...but I don't think I can check in from those either.

Comment: @zwdev2 The airside equivalent of a check-in desk is a transfer desk. They don't handle checked luggage obviously, but they deliver boarding passes and the like.

Comment: Are you sure the check-in window opens at the same time for all flights in the itinerary? I was under the impression that it is relative to the scheduled departure time of each flight, and that this would be the reason (or one of the reasons) why it's sometimes not possible to get the boarding passes for all flights. Traditionally you couldn't check-in until the flight was under "airport control" (when the airport staff are the masters of seating etc, as opposed to the booking desk), though nowadays this may be different (and of course variable from airline to airline).

Comment: COPA says you can check in up to 24 hours before departure time. If the flight leaves GRU on 03/26 5:20PM, why can't I check in from CMB on 03/26 1am?? It's under 24 hours? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by relative departure time.

Comment: In my experience you can check in 24 hours before the first flight. For example if you are flying a United to Europe with a domestic leg in Germany operated by LH, United will give a the boarding pass for the LH leg as well, even of the domestic leg is still 30+ hours out.

Comment: @zwdev2: you are checking in with Emirates, not Copa. From a previous post I understand that Emirates has confirmed that they will give you all boarding passes at check-in. A boarding pass almost always contains a seat assignment, so you should be able to select seats for the Copa flights when you check in with Emirates

Comment: @Hilmar, sorry, Emirates agent said they might give me all the boarding passes (not sure). On their website however I see that the airline that is operating the flight is who I need to check in with. Since COPA is the one operating the flight, I need to check in with COPA.

Comment: @zwdev2 that does indeed change things. If you have to check in with COPA you will be probably be bound by the 24-hour window before the departure in GRU. 3/26 1am Columbo time is indeed to early (by 20 minutes), so could  try mobile check in in Dubai or on the plane from CMB to DXB. Don't rely too much on website info, rules are changing fast, times are strange and a lot of website info is out of date. Your best shot is to call COPA and hope you are getting someone knowledge. Do NOT plan on going landside in GRU. If you want strategies how to check-in in GRU ask another question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've posted a new question on how to check in at GRU.